# How can I build an sbt plugin that stores the name of all implementations of an interface?

Tags: android, sbt

I'm trying to do the impossible and it doesn't seem to be working.  The overall goal is this: I have a Component interface and I would like to show the user a list of classes on the classpath that implement that interface.  The trick is, it has to run in Android.

Near as I can tell this is impossible to do at run time.  The java mechanism ([ServiceLoader](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/index.html?java/util/ServiceLoader.html)) has been intentionally crippled by the Android toolchain, so it doesn't work.  Guava doesn't work on Android, nor does [ClassUtils](http://software.clapper.org/classutil/), nor does [Reflections](https://github.com/ronmamo/reflections).

At this point I've been yak shaving for 8 hours strait and there's no end in sight, so I'm looking for alternative approaches.  My current thinking is to build a plugin (very much like [sbt-spi](https://github.com/nyavro/spi-plugin), but not, because Android hates SPI) that can generate a text file at compile time that lists every class which implements the interface, so that at runtime I can open that file as a resource and then use reflection to start building them.  Is that a reasonable idea?  How should I go about it? (my current approach is "read the [sbt-spi](https://github.com/nyavro/spi-plugin) plugin source and try to copy it", but this seems like a scenario where "ask for wisdom" is a better approach)

Answer (score 0):

Got it!  I ended up using sbt-spi after all (huzzah not reinventing any wheels!) and just moving the output into the intermediate assets directory as part of the resourceGenerators task:

```
lazy val androidEntryPoint = (project in file("android-entry-point"))
  .dependsOn(core, components, androidComponents)
  .enablePlugins(SpiPlugin)
  .settings(commonSettings: _*)
  .settings(resourceGenerators in Compile += Def.task{
    // This task copies the list of Components to the appropriate place to ensure
    // it gets included in an accessible place in the APK
    val res = collectResources.value._1  // item _1 here is for assets, item _2 is for resources.  See the output of sbt "show androidEntryPoint/android:collectResources"
    mapExport.value.toSeq.map { name =>
      IO.move(target.value / name, res / name)
      res / name
    }
  }.taskValue
)
```

That said, I'd love to hear a better approach if you can think of one.  If none turn up in the next week or so I'll mark this one the answer.